# Even though I don't have a this variable, when I am accessing it, I am not getting an error

Tags: php, class, class-members

```
<?php
class Test{
    public $test_1, $test_2;
}


$object = new Test();
$object->test_1 = "THIS IS A TEST";
$object->test_2 = "THIS IS A TEST 2";
$object->test_3 = "THIS IS A TEST 3";

var_dump($object);
```

As you can see I don't have a variable called test_3. But I am not getting an error. It is working perfectly. Why? This is the output I am getting.

```
object(Test)#1 (3) {
  ["test_1"]=>
  string(14) "THIS IS A TEST"
  ["test_2"]=>
  string(16) "THIS IS A TEST 2"
  ["test_3"]=>
  string(16) "THIS IS A TEST 3"
}
```

Comment: You can create member variables on the fly in PHP

Comment: You have setting a new variable. In this community ask for problems...

Comment: @JohnConde, is there any way to restrict it?

Comment: Yes. You can override the __set() magic method and have it error out. Let me see if I can whip up an example.

Comment: You can use magic method __set and put in it stuff that work for that you want

Comment: @eddard.stark John has posted an answer for you below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In PHP you can create public member variables on the fly. If you want to prevent this you can overload the [`__set()` magic method](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.set) and throw an exception if someone tries to do this:

```
class Test{
    public $test_1, $test_2;

    public function __set($name, $value) {
        throw new \Exception('You cannot do this!');
    }
}
```